# Qt 5.8 Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in Qt: platformsupport-private

Tags: qt, qmake, qt5.8

I tried to compile my project on fresh new OS X and Qt 5.8 and got this error. So I figured out that installing Qt 5.7 instead solves my problem but can't find reasonable explanation - nor documentation nor any answers on SO. Why this might happen to Qt modules and how to detect which ones are deprecated later?

Answer (score 4):

It appears Qt5PlatformSupport was modularised and thus split into several libraries.

I've found [this Qt code review entry](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/172485/12/src/platformsupport/platformsupport.pro) which shows that rather than defining a single `QtPlatformSupport` target, the project file now uses the `SUBDIRS` template.
I've also found [this KDE code review entry](https://git.reviewboard.kde.org/r/129268/diff/2-3#0) where you can see that they are using `Qt5PlatformSupport` before Qt Version 5.8.0 and `Qt5FontDatabaseSupport`, `Qt5ThemeSupport` and `Qt5EventDispatcherSupport` after that.

The specific new libraries you require for your project will probably differ.

Comment: Thanks, that helps much! I'm planning to continue using Qt, so I'll need to refactor it later.